# Sphinx Search: get list of words from index by source column

Tags: indexing, sphinx

I have a table(let's call it `my_table`) with two text fields: `title` and `description`. Also I have an index(`my_index`) that uses next source-query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

When I need to get all words and frequencies from `my_index` I use something like:

```
$indexer my_index --buildstops word_freq.txt 1000 --buildfreqs
```

But now, I need to get words that are presented only in column `title`(and their frequencies only from `title` column). What is the best solution to do this?

**Edit:**
It will be perfect, if solution won't build new indexes on disk space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new "index", that only includes the title column. No need to ever build an physical index with it, can just use it with --buildstops :)

Index inheritence, allows its creation with very compact bit in the config file

```
source my_index_title : my_index {
   sql_query = SELECT id,title from my_table
}
index my_index_title : my_index {
   source = my_index_title
   path = /tmp/my_index_title
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the easiest way. But maybe there is another solution that doesn't require to build new index? I've 5 indexes that contain such columns and I don't want to build additional indexes.

Comment: As I already said you DON'T actully need to build these indexes. The only 'disk space' they use is the few extra bytes in the config file.

Comment: Unfortunately I do have index with two sources. Of cource this isn't a big problem but it gives some redundancy.